# Why this map is a bijection?

Tags: functions

Let ${\bf \large F}(n,d)$  be the set of all functions from the set $\{1,\cdots,n\} $ to the set  $\{1,\cdots,d\}$. We consider the following map 
$$
\star: {\bf \large F}(m,d)\times {\bf \large F}(n-m,d) \to {\bf \large F}(n,d): (g,h) \mapsto g \star h,
$$
such that $(g\star h)(k) = g(k)$ for $k \leq m$ and $(g \star h)(m+k) = h(k)$ for $k \geq 1$.

Why this map is a bijection?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a bijection because it is injective and surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it has an inverse $G\colon\mathbf{F}(n,d)\longrightarrow\mathbf{F}(m,d)\times\mathbf{F}(n-m,d)$. If $f\in\mathbf{F}(n,d)$, define $G_1(f)\in\mathbf{F}(m,d)$ by $G_1(f)(k)=f(k)$ and define $G_2(f)\in\mathbf{F}(n-m,d)$ by $G_2(f)(k)=f(k-m)$. Then, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}G\colon&\mathbf{F}(n,d)&\longrightarrow&\mathbf{F}(m,d)\times\mathbf{F}(n-m,d)\\&f&\mapsto&\bigl(G_1(f),G_2(f)\bigr).\end{array}$$Then $G=F^{-1}$.